# On-hover transitions not reversing in Safari

Tags: css, safari, webkit, transition

I'm using transitions to move text when their parent element is hovered. However, the transition is not reversed when testing in Safari. This results in the text quickly jumping back to the beginning if you stop hovering the parent element before the transition has finished. If you do this in Chrome, the transition reverses back to the beginning.

Can this be fixed in Safari in some way?

[GIF showing Safari & Chrome comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYF88.gif)

[Safari not reversing clearification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DGM2.gif)

**Overview of CSS:**

```
.infoContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    transition: bottom .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: bottom .5s ease-in-out;
    bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```
.body:hover .infoContainer {
    bottom: calc(100% - 1.8rem - 1.3rem - 1rem);
}
```

*Running Safari Version 16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12), Chrome Version 108.0.5359.98.*

---

**Expectations and attempts:**
I was expecting the transition to be smoothly reversed like it is in Google Chrome. I've tried using the following CSS without success.

```
-webkit-transition: bottom .5s ease-in-out;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I will write my answer here.

You can add this

```
.infoContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1rem;
    transition: bottom .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: bottom .5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 1ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 1ms;
}
```

It should help on safari ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This did unfortunately not fix the issue. [It still looks like this](https://i.imgur.com/2RjdNza.gif)